# Discrepancy in behavior of Linux loaders (ld-linux-x86-64) between Glibc 2.12 and Glibc 2.17

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, glibc, ldd, rpath

I'm trying to compile the same lib on two x86 separate machines.
Both use the same toolchain (exactly same set of files) but have different Glibc versions.

When I run command `LD_DEBUG=libs /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --list ./libl2ps.so` I notice the following discrepancy between the 2 Linux loaders:

**Machine 1** (with Glibc 2.12):

```
 19943: find library=libm.so.6 [0]; searching
 19943:  search path=/ebs/frperies/repo/gnb/uplane/build/prefix-root/asik-x86_64-ps_lfs-dynamic-linker-on/toolchain/sysroots/core2-64-pc-linux-gnu/usr/lib64:...:/ebs/frperies/repo/gnb/uplane/build_bbp/l2_ps/build/.      (RPATH from file ./libl2ps.so)
 19943:   trying file=/ebs/frperies/repo/gnb/uplane/build/prefix-root/asik-x86_64-ps_lfs-dynamic-linker-on/toolchain/sysroots/core2-64-pc-linux-gnu/usr/lib64/libm.so.6
 19943: 
 19943: find library=libgcc_s.so.1 [0]; searching
 ...
```

In this case the Linux loader selects lib `libm.so.6` from the toolchain path based on RPATH of lib `libl2ps.so`.

**Machine 2** (with Glibc 2.17):

```
 10699: find library=libm.so.6 [0]; searching
 10699:  search path=/home/frperies/repo/gnb/uplane/build/prefix-root/asik-x86_64-ps_lfs-dynamic-linker-on/toolchain/sysroots/core2-64-pc-linux-gnu/usr/lib64:/home/frperies/repo/gnb/uplane/build/prefix-root/asik-x86_64-ps_lfs-dynamic-linker-on/toolchain/sysroots/core2-64-pc-linux-gnu/lib64:/home/frperies/repo/gnb/uplane/build/prefix-root/asik-x86_64-ps_lfs-dynamic-linker-on/toolchain/sysroots/core2-64-pc-linux-gnu/usr/lib:/home/frperies/repo/gnb/uplane/build_bbp/l2_ps/build/.        (RPATH from file ./libl2ps.so)
 10699:   trying file=/home/frperies/repo/gnb/uplane/build/prefix-root/asik-x86_64-ps_lfs-dynamic-linker-on/toolchain/sysroots/core2-64-pc-linux-gnu/usr/lib64/libm.so.6
 10699:   trying file=/home/frperies/repo/gnb/uplane/build/prefix-root/asik-x86_64-ps_lfs-dynamic-linker-on/toolchain/sysroots/core2-64-pc-linux-gnu/lib64/libm.so.6
 10699:   trying file=/home/frperies/repo/gnb/uplane/build/prefix-root/asik-x86_64-ps_lfs-dynamic-linker-on/toolchain/sysroots/core2-64-pc-linux-gnu/usr/lib/libm.so.6
 10699:   trying file=/home/frperies/repo/gnb/uplane/build_bbp/l2_ps/build/./libm.so.6
 10699:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
 10699:   trying file=/lib64/libm.so.6
```

As for Machine 1, the loader attempts from RPATH of `libl2ps.so` to select lib `libm.so.6` from toolchain path but skip it for some reason and try further other paths. Finally it selects `libm.so.6`from the system path `/lib64/`.

The RPATH of the 2 libs `lib2ps.so` are exactly the same. The two files `libm.so.6` are also exactly the same on both machines (checked with `md5sum`).

I don't understand this differences of behavior between the 2 Linux loaders.
Do you see any reason what would explain this discrepancy ?

Thank you very much for your answers.

**Update:**

Thank you **yugr** for your answer.

Output of `readelf -h` gives only differences on fields "*Entry point address*" and "*Start of section headers*" and there is no other differences so I think it will not help.

Regarding using `dlopen()`/`dlerror()`, I've done a little executable with the following statement:

```
dlopen("/home/frperies/repo/gnb/uplane/build/prefix-root/asik-x86_64-ps_lfs-dynamic-linker-on/toolchain/sysroots/core2-64-pc-linux-gnu/usr/lib64/libm-2.28.so", RTLD_LAZY);
```

On machine 1 it works as expected:

```
C++ dlopen demo

Opening libm-2.28.so...
Closing library...
```

On machine 2 it fails and dlerror() gives the following output:

```
Cannot open library: /home/frperies/repo/gnb/uplane/build/prefix-root/asik-x86_64-ps_lfs-dynamic-linker-on/toolchain/sysroots/core2-64-pc-linux-gnu/usr/lib64/libm-2.28.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

but the file `libm-2-28.so` **really exists** on my file system:

```
$ ls -l /home/frperies/repo/gnb/uplane/build/prefix-root/asik-x86_64-ps_lfs-dynamic-linker-on/toolchain/sysroots/core2-64-pc-linux-gnu/usr/lib64/libm-2.28.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 frperies linseeusers_lte_espoo 1682944 Oct  5 13:50 /home/frperies/repo/gnb/uplane/build/prefix-root/asik-x86_64-ps_lfs-dynamic- linker-on/toolchain/sysroots/core2-64-pc-linux-gnu/usr/lib64/libm-2.28.so
```

This is very weird, what could lead to this situation ???

Thanks

**Update 2:**

That is true that I haven't pointed out that machine 1 is a RHEL6.8 distro while machine 2 is RHEL7.4 distro. I (naively?) didn't think this really matters...

On machine 1:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/osrelease
4.4.115-1.NSN.el6.x86_64

$ uname -a
Linux sq24-3 4.4.115-1.NSN.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Feb 12 12:35:46 CET 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ readelf -n libl2ps.so 

Notes at offset 0x00000270 with length 0x00000024:
  Owner                 Data size   Description
  GNU                  0x00000014   NT_GNU_BUILD_ID (unique build ID bitstring)
  Build ID: b598468830fdf2f61eda25553b9a367c4d28cdc9
```

On machine 2:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/osrelease
3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64

$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jul 6 19:56:57 EDT 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ readelf -n libl2ps.so 

Displaying notes found at file offset 0x00000270 with length 0x00000024:
  Owner                 Data size   Description 
  GNU                  0x00000014   NT_GNU_BUILD_ID (unique build ID bitstring)
  Build ID: 5829181bc0502233748149369108915ea7b10e8f
```

Does it help ?

Thanks

**Update 3:**

```
$ readelf -n libm.so.6 

Notes at offset 0x00000238 with length 0x00000024:
  Owner                 Data size   Description
  GNU                  0x00000014   NT_GNU_BUILD_ID (unique build ID bitstring)
  Build ID: 0d84c7247dd76008c096719043e5592735a1c4bd

Notes at offset 0x0000025c with length 0x00000020:
  Owner                 Data size   Description
  GNU                  0x00000010   NT_GNU_ABI_TAG (ABI version tag)
  OS: Linux, ABI: 4.4.0
```

So, how to interpret this ABI version number set to 4.4.0 ??

Thanks

Thank you yugr and Employed Russian for your answers!!
I will give it a try by upgrading my Kernel version on Machine 2.

Thanks
Regards

Comment: Glibc performs a bunch of checks on load (see [here](https://github.molgen.mpg.de/git-mirror/glibc/blob/f7a9f785e547bd599dee496fd906a28bcb4ec7fe/elf/dl-load.c#L1492)) and it's hard to say which one failed. Can you post output of `readelf -h`? Can you try `dlopen`ing you library (via absolute path) in executable and inspecting `dlerror` on fail?

Comment: Hi yugr, thank you for your answer...please read update above.

Comment: You want to run `readelf -n .../libm.so.6` as *that* is the library that the loader is refusing to use. The notes on `libl2ps.so` are *irrelevant*.

Comment: @EmployedRussian: You are right, sorry for this mistake. Please refer to Update 3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message that you see is the infamously confusing `ENOENT` errno. I see two instances of it in `dl-load.c`:

- [checking OS compatibility](https://github.molgen.mpg.de/git-mirror/glibc/blob/f7a9f785e547bd599dee496fd906a28bcb4ec7fe/elf/dl-load.c#L1761)
- [loading non-setuid to setuid process](https://github.molgen.mpg.de/git-mirror/glibc/blob/f7a9f785e547bd599dee496fd906a28bcb4ec7fe/elf/dl-load.c#L1880)

I suspect the first one fails in your case which would mean that OS kernel is incompatible between two machines. `ld.so` [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) indeed says that

> Each shared object can inform the dynamic linker of the
>   minimum kernel ABI version that it requires.  (This
>   requirement is encoded in an ELF note section that is viewable
>   via readelf -n as a section labeled NT_GNU_ABI_TAG.)  At run
>   time, the dynamic linker determines the ABI version of the
>   running kernel and will reject loading shared objects that
>   specify minimum ABI versions that exceed that ABI version.

`NT_GNU_ABI_TAG` is 4.4.0 which means that you run a program expecting a minimum 4.4 kernel on a 3.10 kernel. Theoretically newer Glibc should run on older kernels as well but in your case Glibc was probly built with explicit `--enable-kernel` flag which prevents it's usage on kernels before 4.4 (see e.g. [this explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13780) of `--enable-kernel`).

As a workaround, you may try to fool Glibc by overriding kernel version on machine 2 via

```
export LD_ASSUME_KERNEL=4.4.0
```

but it may not work if `libm` makes 4.4-specific syscalls that are not really present on 3.10.

Comment: @frperies Ok, we might be close. What is the output of `uname` on machine where the problematic `libm.so` was compiled?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have this information because this file libm.so comes in with the whole toolchain which was built on a third separate machine. I would think it is pretty much aligned with the kernel version of machine 1.

Comment: Please refer to update 3, it turns out that ABI number for libm.so is 4.4.0 but I don't really knows what it means...thanks

Comment: @frperies The answer now explains what 4.4.0 means -- it's the minimum Linux kernel version that this build of GLIBC is compatible with. You must either upgrade the kernel, or rebuild sysroot GLIBC with `--enable-kernel=3.10`.

Comment: Thank you for your very clear answers ! I was not aware of those aspects and underlying interactions between Glibc and Kernel/ABI versions.

Comment: @frperies Np, you might want to accept the answer if it helped.